# Discrete Choice Model with Some Levels Combined

Tags: multinomial-distribution, choice-modeling

I am new to discrete choice modeling, and I am half way through reading Train's [Discrete Choice Methods with Simulation](http://eml.berkeley.edu/books/choice2.html).

My question is: what do I do if some of the choice levels are combined? For instance, if there are choices 1,2,3,4,5, but I only know whether an individual selected 1, or 2, or one of 3,4,5, but not exactly which one of 3,4,5.

I can see how the likelihood function can be constructed in this case -- it would be a marginal likelihood if I am not mistaken.

I would like to know:

1. What is the name of this sort of model. I have not been able to find anything on google on my own.
2. What are some practical implemnations (i.e. software packages) that are already out there?

Thank you very much!